# Using "the best of" with uncountable and countable nouns

Tags: superlatives

Is it correct to write:

> "It is not the best of quality" when referring to, for instance, the quality of a video? (Quality being an uncountable noun)

Can one use "of" in this sentence? (As in "the best of luck") Why/why not?

When using countable nouns one could say "the best of friends", right?

Comment: I would say either "It is not of the best quality" or "It is not the best in quality." I'm not sure there is a reason for this other than what's idiomatic. Somehow, we say "riding in a car" and "riding on a bus." Prepositions are tricky.

Comment: This is **very** involved. I'll just address the false comparison 'When using countable nouns one could say "the best [/closest] of friends [/pals / buddies]", right?' makes. You can't say 'They are the best of siblings / co-workers / teammates / colleagues / partners'. And 'They are the best of peoples' doesn't have the 'closest' sense. // Also, 'the best of luck' as a wish is really a condensed version of 'I hope you enjoy the best of what luck is available'. Comparisons of similar structures are often highly misleading. I took the dog a bone / I took the dog a walk.

Comment: Ok, but "It's not the best of quality" is out of the question? Speaking about what's idiomatic?      Thank you for answering!